# IronPython SqlCommand affects rows, but doesn't save changes

Tags: c#, ironpython, sql-server-2014, sqlcommand

I have an Update and Insert scripts in IronPython, so when I run them via
`ExecuteNonQuery()` it returns 1 affected row (as expected), but when I look in db (or run `select` query), there's no any changes.

```
def update(pConnection, transaction, serialName, serial_counter):
    query = """ UPDATE [EM_DEMO].[dbo].[tblCounter]
                    SET [Counter] =  @counter
                WHERE [ChiaveTabella] = @serial_column
            """;

    print 'query: ', query; # DEBUG INFO

    cmd = pConnection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@counter', serial_counter.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@serial_column', serialName);

    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if not rowsAffected == 1:
        print 'Error during update! rows affected:', rowsAffected;
        return False;
    else:
        print 'Complete!';
        return True;
```

But when I run the same code from native C#: it works well!
Can anybody help me: what's the problem?

Comment: Did you "commit" the transaction?

Comment: @Tung, when i'm trying to `transaction.Commit()` after `ExecuteNonQuery()`, it throws an exception: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to commit changes manually (in native C# worked without commiting), and thrown exceptions, so it is necessary to `transaction.Commit()` after every execution.

```
# ...

rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

transaction.Commit();

# ...
```